# Getting an error with pip3: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

Tags: python, pip

When every I try to use pip3, either with pip3 install *package*  or pip3 list, or any other command that includes pip3 I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

So far I have already tried to run `sudo apt remove python3-pip` then running `sudo apt install python3-pip` but that doesnt work. And I also looked at doing this, **look at the code portion below**, to try and uninstall and then reinstall pip3, but nothing I have done so far seems to be working.

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip  
sudo rm -rf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip'  
sudo apt install python3-pip   
cd
cd .local/lib/python3/site-packages
sudo rm -rf pip*  
cd
cd .local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
sudo rm -rf pip*  
sudo pip3 install xlwt
```

Comment: Trying installing a package using `python3 -m pip3 install x`. What distro and version are you on?

Comment: What is your linux distribution?

Comment: @GAD3R the distribution is 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that installed pip is linked to `pip3`? I had a similar error some time ago. The installed pip for my python version was simply linked to `pip`, while there was an old version liked to `pip3`. Just try run:

```
pip --version
```

This shows you if its pip for python 2 or 3.

Comment: So my pip is linked to my python 2.7 distribution. how would I like it to my python 3.5 distribution

Comment: Did you try if pip3 (linked to python 3) is working correctly - if it is just set an alias for pip to pip3.